# Как управлять Layout - ом отдельного итема ListLayout

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые.
Есть такая задача.
Вывести ListView а в нём в каждом элементе определенные данные с ArrayList.
Но есть один нюанс. По дефолту (стандарту) каждый элемент показан лишь на половину (он состоит из 2 лайаутов у одного из которых visibility = gone), а по клику на этот итем он должен быть показан полностью(у обоих лайаутов visibility = visible), по повторному клику обратно спрятать дополнительную часть.
Понятно что я создам кастомный адаптер и засуну в него данные, но как мне разворачивать и сворачивать именно тот элемент на который я тапну, а не последний?
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // используем созданные, но не используемые view
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_item, parent, false);

    Product p = getProduct(position);
    text1.setText(p.getName());
    text2.setText(p.getLastName());

    layoutParent.setOnClicListner(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(layiutTwo.getVisibiliti() == View.VISIBLE){
                layiutTwo.setVisibiliti().View.GONE;
            } else {
                layiutTwo.setVisibiliti().View.VISIBLE;
            }
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: В `getView` методе адаптера повесьте на вьюхи слушатели нажатий и меняйте видимость отдельных элементов. Но при этом придётся убрать слушатели нажтий, повешенные на адаптер снаружи.

Comment: К сожалению это не работает.
Точнее работает не корректно.
Таким образом по клинку на любой элемент раскрывается всегда последний.

Comment: Это точно работает. У вас просто где-то ошибка в коде. Покажите код.

Comment: в Product добавьте boolean isSelected, в адаптере по клику меняйте свойство p.isSelected и делайте видимость/невидимость